# Wordpress ACF Taxonomy Term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Using Wordpress and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) (ACF), I ran into some strange behavior for one custom field I created for a custom taxonomy.

The field is showing, but each time I fill some content into it and save the taxonomy its empty afterwards. It doesn’t seem to have anything to do with the version of ACF or Wordpress. I tested it on the latest Wordpress Version too.
Neither does the field type I add to the custom field make any difference.

Custom Field = Lightbox Editor
ACF Version: 4.3.9
WP Version: 4.1

**Screenshots:**

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Does work in up-to-date versions.. Maybe another plugin is conflicting?

Comment: no other plugins activated. 
But I solved it in a different way for now.